# SEO Realestate Listing Site - Indexing and Linking to CSS/JS

Tags: html, wordpress, seo

I am involved in a project that is a real-estate listing site. The site has the ability to post advertisements, have static pages and also a blog. Since this could be easily implemented using WordPress which I have some experience with I proceeded with WP.

When functional the site might host hundreds perhaps thousands of active real-estate advertisements. We are using Permalinks. The advertisements are relatively static. Once posted would remain so. But the widgets will  update the side bars with latest advertisements and posts.

**QUESTION 1:** My question is, is it OK to index the whole site. I ask this question because I came across some blog posts saying that indexing such listings is a bad idea. I also came with some blog posts saying to use Schema (for example to define 'Price', 'Rating' etc) when having such content.

**QUESTION 2:** I have CSS and JS that are page specific. At the moment I embed them in the header and thus pages not needing them also have to load them. I hear that modern browsers will cache these so it will not burden the web-server.

By accident I had put the 'link' to a CSS within the **body** tag of the HTML page and it worked without an issue. I am wondering if this is a bad practice.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions, so you should probably try to ask your first question in some place SEO-related. Also, you should ask only one question at a time. If you have 2 questions, you should ask them separately. Finally, I don't really understand what's being asked on the second question. Maybe you should try explaining a bit more what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1)** It might be a better way of displaying the data and entering it for future use, but I doubt it would have any effect on SEO. It may be worth re-posting this question separate here:

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com
```

**Question 2)** You can use conditional formatting in your template files to load the CSS/JS on certain pages. e.g. Appearance -> Editor -> Header (header.php or whatever file name your template may use)

```
<?php
if(is_front_page()) {
echo "your custom CSS and JS here";
} ?>
```

That example is for the front page, but if it is another page try replacing that second line with: **if(is_page('contact')) {** where contact would be replaced with your page slug or id.

While loading the CSS in the body would work, it is bad practice as technically page elements could load before the CSS file is loaded. This could be an issue for older browsers.

Hope it helps,
Jeremy.